# require.js and three.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

Tags: three.js, requirejs

I'm trying to include a threejs visual in a documentation page generated via Julia's Documenter.jl package. Unfortunately, the way Documenter currently handles javascript components is via require.js and it appears to break three.js (or its modules) with the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

My [self-contained example is like this](https://codepen.io/bapt/pen/mdWmyoM)

```
var container = document.getElementById("three_container");

scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xeeeeee );

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 200;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x000, 1.0);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


const frontSpot = new THREE.SpotLight(0xeeeece);
frontSpot.position.set(1000, 1000, 1000);
scene.add(frontSpot);

const frontSpot2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xddddce);
frontSpot2.position.set(-500, -500, -500);
scene.add(frontSpot2);


    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1));

    function createSphere(radius, segments) {
    
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xfcc742,
  emissive: 0x111111,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  metalness: 0.8,
  roughness: 0.6,
});
        return new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments),
            material
        );
    }

    // sphere params
    var radius   = 1,
        segments = 36,
        rotation = 6;  
         
// spheres

   var sphere1 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere1.position.x = 35.35533905932738;
                   sphere1.position.y = 35.35533905932737;
                   sphere1.position.z = 99.99999999999999;
                   sphere1.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere1.rotation.z = 3.9269908169872414;
                   sphere1.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere1.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere1.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere1);
var sphere2 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere2.position.x = 3.061616997868383e-15;
                   sphere2.position.y = 50.0;
                   sphere2.position.z = 74.99999999999999;
                   sphere2.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere2.rotation.z = 4.71238898038469;
                   sphere2.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere2.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere2.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere2);
var sphere3 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere3.position.x = -35.35533905932737;
                   sphere3.position.y = 35.35533905932738;
                   sphere3.position.z = 49.999999999999986;
                   sphere3.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere3.rotation.z = -0.7853981633974483;
                   sphere3.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere3.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere3.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere3);
var sphere4 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere4.position.x = -50.0;
                   sphere4.position.y = 6.123233995736766e-15;
                   sphere4.position.z = 24.999999999999986;
                   sphere4.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere4.rotation.z = -2.220446049250313e-16;
                   sphere4.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere4.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere4.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere4);
var sphere5 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere5.position.x = -35.355339059327385;
                   sphere5.position.y = -35.35533905932737;
                   sphere5.position.z = 0.0;
                   sphere5.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere5.rotation.z = 0.7853981633974481;
                   sphere5.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere5.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere5.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere5);
var sphere6 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere6.position.x = -9.184850993605149e-15;
                   sphere6.position.y = -50.0;
                   sphere6.position.z = -25.000000000000014;
                   sphere6.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere6.rotation.z = 1.5707963267948963;
                   sphere6.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere6.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere6.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere6);
var sphere7 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere7.position.x = 35.35533905932737;
                   sphere7.position.y = -35.355339059327385;
                   sphere7.position.z = -49.999999999999986;
                   sphere7.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere7.rotation.z = 2.356194490192345;
                   sphere7.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere7.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere7.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere7);
var sphere8 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere8.position.x = 50.0;
                   sphere8.position.y = -1.2246467991473532e-14;
                   sphere8.position.z = -75.00000000000001;
                   sphere8.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere8.rotation.z = 3.141592653589793;
                   sphere8.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere8.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere8.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere8);
var sphere9 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere9.position.x = 35.355339059327385;
                   sphere9.position.y = 35.35533905932737;
                   sphere9.position.z = -100.00000000000001;
                   sphere9.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere9.rotation.z = 3.9269908169872414;
                   sphere9.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere9.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere9.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere9);
var sphere10 = createSphere(radius, segments);
                   sphere10.position.x = 1.5308084989341916e-14;
                   sphere10.position.y = 50.0;
                   sphere10.position.z = -124.99999999999999;
                   sphere10.scale.set(10,10,20);
                   sphere10.rotation.z = 4.71238898038469;
                   sphere10.rotation.x = 2.137707831735906;
                   sphere10.rotation.y = 0.0;
                   sphere10.rotation.order = 'ZXY';
                   scene.add(sphere10);

// end spheres


document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//renderer.render(scene, camera);

    
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

    function render() {
        controls.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
render();
```

I've read and tried various suggestions to make the THREE namespace available or something, but haven't had any luck. If I manually insert

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
```

at the top of the page `<head>`, everything works fine, but I cannot change the order when it's generated by Documenter. Any thoughts on how to work around this?

Edit: The requirejs configuration generated by Documenter looks like this:

```
// Generated by Documenter.jl
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'highlight-julia': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/languages/julia.min',
    'headroom': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headroom/0.10.3/headroom.min',
    'jqueryui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min',
    'katex-auto-render': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.11.1/contrib/auto-render.min',
    'jquery': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min',
    'headroom-jquery': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headroom/0.10.3/jQuery.headroom.min',
    'katex': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.11.1/katex.min',
    'highlight': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/highlight.min',
    'highlight-julia-repl': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/languages/julia-repl.min',
  },
  shim: {
  "highlight-julia": {
    "deps": [
      "highlight"
    ]
  },
  "katex-auto-render": {
    "deps": [
      "katex"
    ]
  },
  "headroom-jquery": {
    "deps": [
      "jquery",
      "headroom"
    ]
  },
  "highlight-julia-repl": {
    "deps": [
      "highlight"
    ]
  }
}
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require(['jquery', 'katex', 'katex-auto-render'], function($, katex, renderMathInElement) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  renderMathInElement(
    document.body,
    {
  "delimiters": [
    {
      "left": "$",
      "right": "$",
      "display": false
    },
    {
      "left": "$$",
      "right": "$$",
      "display": true
    },
    {
      "left": "\\[",
      "right": "\\]",
      "display": true
    }
  ]
}

  );
})

})
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require(['jquery', 'highlight', 'highlight-julia', 'highlight-julia-repl'], function($, hljs) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    hljs.initHighlighting();
})

})
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require(['jquery', 'headroom', 'headroom-jquery'], function($, Headroom) {

// Manages the top navigation bar (hides it when the user starts scrolling down on the
// mobile).
window.Headroom = Headroom; // work around buggy module loading?
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#documenter .docs-navbar').headroom({
    "tolerance": {"up": 10, "down": 10},
  });
})

})
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require(['jquery'], function($) {

// Modal settings dialog
$(document).ready(function() {
  var settings = $('#documenter-settings');
  $('#documenter-settings-button').click(function(){
    settings.toggleClass('is-active');
  });
  // Close the dialog if X is clicked
  $('#documenter-settings button.delete').click(function(){
    settings.removeClass('is-active');
  });
  // Close dialog if ESC is pressed
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) settings.removeClass('is-active');
  });
});

})
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require(['jquery'], function($) {

// Manages the showing and hiding of the sidebar.
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sidebar = $("#documenter > .docs-sidebar");
  var sidebar_button = $("#documenter-sidebar-button")
  sidebar_button.click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    sidebar.toggleClass('visible');
    if (sidebar.hasClass('visible')) {
      // Makes sure that the current menu item is visible in the sidebar.
      $("#documenter .docs-menu a.is-active").focus();
    }
  });
  $("#documenter > .docs-main").bind('click', function(ev) {
    if ($(ev.target).is(sidebar_button)) {
      return;
    }
    if (sidebar.hasClass('visible')) {
      sidebar.removeClass('visible');
    }
  });
})

// Resizes the package name / sitename in the sidebar if it is too wide.
// Inspired by: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  e = $("#documenter .docs-autofit");
  function resize() {
    var L = parseInt(e.css('max-width'), 10);
    var L0 = e.width();
    if(L0 > L) {
      var h0 = parseInt(e.css('font-size'), 10);
      e.css('font-size', L * h0 / L0);
      // TODO: make sure it survives resizes?
    }
  }
  // call once and then register events
  resize();
  $(window).resize(resize);
  $(window).on('orientationchange', resize);
});

// Scroll the navigation bar to the currently selected menu item
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sidebar = $("#documenter .docs-menu").get(0);
  var active = $("#documenter .docs-menu .is-active").get(0);
  if(typeof active !== 'undefined') {
    sidebar.scrollTop = active.offsetTop - sidebar.offsetTop - 15;
  }
})

})
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require(['jquery'], function($) {

function set_theme(theme) {
  var active = null;
  var disabled = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets[i];
    var themename = ss.ownerNode.getAttribute("data-theme-name");
    if(themename === null) continue; // ignore non-theme stylesheets
    // Find the active theme
    if(themename === theme) active = ss;
    else disabled.push(ss);
  }
  if(active !== null) {
    active.disabled = false;
    if(active.ownerNode.getAttribute("data-theme-primary") === null) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = "theme--" + theme;
    } else {
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = "";
    }
    disabled.forEach(function(ss){
      ss.disabled = true;
    });
  }

  // Store the theme in localStorage
  if(typeof(window.localStorage) !== "undefined") {
    window.localStorage.setItem("documenter-theme", theme);
  } else {
    console.error("Browser does not support window.localStorage");
  }
}

// Theme picker setup
$(document).ready(function() {
  // onchange callback
  $('#documenter-themepicker').change(function themepick_callback(ev){
    var themename = $('#documenter-themepicker option:selected').attr('value');
    set_theme(themename);
  });

  // Make sure that the themepicker displays the correct theme when the theme is retrieved
  // from localStorage
  if(typeof(window.localStorage) !== "undefined") {
    var theme =  window.localStorage.getItem("documenter-theme");
    if(theme !== null) {
      $('#documenter-themepicker option').each(function(i,e) {
        e.selected = (e.value === theme);
      })
    } else {
      $('#documenter-themepicker option').each(function(i,e) {
        e.selected = $("html").hasClass(`theme--${e.value}`);
      })
    }
  }
})

})
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require(['jquery'], function($) {

// update the version selector with info from the siteinfo.js and ../versions.js files
$(document).ready(function() {
  var version_selector = $("#documenter .docs-version-selector");
  var version_selector_select = $("#documenter .docs-version-selector select");

  version_selector_select.change(function(x) {
    target_href = version_selector_select.children("option:selected").get(0).value;
    window.location.href = target_href;
  });

  // add the current version to the selector based on siteinfo.js, but only if the selector is empty
  if (typeof DOCUMENTER_CURRENT_VERSION !== 'undefined' && $('#version-selector > option').length == 0) {
    var option = $("<option value='#' selected='selected'>" + DOCUMENTER_CURRENT_VERSION + "</option>");
    version_selector_select.append(option);
  }

  if (typeof DOC_VERSIONS !== 'undefined') {
    var existing_versions = version_selector_select.children("option");
    var existing_versions_texts = existing_versions.map(function(i,x){return x.text});
    DOC_VERSIONS.forEach(function(each) {
      var version_url = documenterBaseURL + "/../" + each;
      var existing_id = $.inArray(each, existing_versions_texts);
      // if not already in the version selector, add it as a new option,
      // otherwise update the old option with the URL and enable it
      if (existing_id == -1) {
        var option = $("<option value='" + version_url + "'>" + each + "</option>");
        version_selector_select.append(option);
      } else {
        var option = existing_versions[existing_id];
        option.value = version_url;
        option.disabled = false;
      }
    });
  }

  // only show the version selector if the selector has been populated
  if (version_selector_select.children("option").length > 0) {
    version_selector.toggleClass("visible");
  }
})

})
```

Comment: What's the `Documenter.jl` package? Why won't it let you change the order of your scripts? This is an essential requisite for any JavaScript framework: first it loads your libraries, then it loads your custom code that needs those libraries to be accessible. This sounds like a Documenter shortcoming, not a three.js issue.

Comment: The Documenter.jl developers [are well aware that the current js-loading layout is not ideal](https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl/issues/1433), and they'd probably be happy to get some help in refactoring the js loading part. In the meantime, is there a workaround that could be used?

Comment: If Documenter.jl lets you use `<script type="module">` then you could import Three.js as a module in your code. [See this page](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation) under "Install from CDN or static hosting" and you could use version @0.128 for the latest build.

Comment: Are you able to modify the RequireJS config?

Comment: Please provide the script which is loading the scripts

Comment: it [doesn't look like](https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl/issues/1247) one can change the config at present :/